# How to add a checkbox into a table

Tags: javascript, checkbox

```
    function addRow() {
    var a = document.getElementById("modulename").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("duedate").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("duetime").value;
    var d = document.getElementById("worktype").value;
    var e = document.getElementById("notes").value;
    //var f = <input type="checkbox" id="complete" value="no">
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    //var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
    cell1.innerHTML = a;
    cell2.innerHTML = b;
    cell3.innerHTML = c;
    cell4.innerHTML = d;
    cell5.innerHTML = e;
    //cell6.innerHTML = e;
    //document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = x;
```

I've commented the checkbox part of the code out for now as it wasn't functioning before hand, new to HTML, any help is appreciated.

I've been stuck at it for an hour or two now and just can't figure out whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as the same way you were doing but within `''` as below:

```
var f = '<input type="checkbox" id="complete" value="no">';
```

and then

```
cell6.innerHTML=f
```

Answer (score 0):

Since at this point your element is just a string literal, you need to put it in quotation marks:

```
var f = '<input type="checkbox" id="complete" value="no">';
```

I'm using single quotes here, because the string already contains double quotes. Otherwise, you would have to escape them:

```
var f = "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"complete\" value=\"no\">";
```